# Rails 6: make number_to_phone clcikable

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I make the following `number_to_phone` clickable in to order dial this phone number?

`<%= number_to_phone(@business.phone_number, area_code: true) %>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```rb
formatted_phone_number = number_to_phone(@business.phone_number, area_code: true)

link_to formatted_phone_number, "tel:#{formatted_phone_number}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jean-Michel Gigault ... I changed your answer to this and it worked fine for me: `<%= link_to number_to_phone(@business.phone_number, area_code: true), "tel:#{number_to_phone(@business.phone_number, area_code: true)}" %>`.  Thanks for the help, change your answer so I can Accept it.

Comment: Note that I edited my initial answer (because I had inverted the order of the arguments).
You should avoid to call `number_to_phone` twice because it will process transformation twice. Just do it once and store result in a local variable.